# Why I can not add a network location in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

The network settings of this system are exactly the same as other systems, but it encounters an error when add network location.
I have a ping server on this computer but I still get this error.

How to fix this?
[image]

Comment: are you part of a domain and both systems are members of it, or alternately, do you have a non-domain user account with the same name and password on both systems? you can login from a domain system to a non-domain system using a non-domain user account, but you cannot login to a domain system from a non-domain system.

Comment: Try `net.exe use \\192.168.1.19\admin$ /user:localhost\username` beforehand.  If 192.168.1.19 is part of a domain, then replace `localhost` with `domain`.  This assumes you know an administrator account for accessing 192.168.1.19, and that the remote `admin$` share is accessible from your computer. It's quite possible that you may be blocked by a firewall.